# Mapping a url to one servlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using the class **org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController** to wrap a servlet, that we need to process one http request in Spring MVC, but reference  **spring mvc version 3.2** guide says:

```
There are also several things no longer possible:

Select a controller first with a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping or BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
```

So then this is not possible any longer, as the api says:

```
<bean id="urlMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="interceptors">
 <list>
   <ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptor"/>
 </list>
</property>
<property name="mappings">
 <props>
   <prop key="*.do">strutsWrappingController</prop>
 </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="strutsWrappingController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController">
<property name="servletClass">
 <value>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</value>
</property>
<property name="servletName">
 <value>action</value>
</property>
<property name="initParameters">
 <props>
   <prop key="config">/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</prop>
 </props>
</property>
</bean>
```

how can i map a url to a ServletWrappingController bean?

Thanks in advance.